# Annotation @JoinTable How to use scala programming

Tags: spring, hibernate, scala

Using Annotation @jointable in scala programming got an errror

i import this

```
import javax.persistence.JoinTable
```

The code

```
@BeanProperty
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "LW_USER_ROLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERACCOUNT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
                Here got the compilation error ---^                                                            ^------ and here
var roles:List[Role]
```

compilation ERROR

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - expected start of definition
    - annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: { <empty>; (){<error>} }
     {<error>}
    - type mismatch; found : Unit required: Array[javax.persistence.JoinColumn]
    - expected start of definition
    - annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: { <empty>; (){<error>} }
     {<error>}
    - type mismatch; found : Unit required: Array[javax.persistence.JoinColumn]
```

i use this annotation in java but there is no error .. if anyone know the answer please share here.

with regards MILANO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add meta-annotation to the annotation-type. For JoinColumn try this:

```
import annotation.target.field

@(JoinColumn @field)(name = "USERACCOUNT_ID")
```

You can also define type aliases, e.g.:

```
object MyAnnotations {
  type JoinColumn = jpa.JoinColumn @field
}
```

and then import these annotations instead of the original ones.
see also: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3421

Comment: Your answer is not for this question. This is a COMPILATION error, you are solving a runtime error  I am facing with the same problem, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319628/how-to-use-annotation-jointable-containing-joincolumn-in-scala