# How to use Annotation @JoinTable containing @JoinColumn in scala

Tags: scala

In Java the following is valid:

```
@JoinTable(name = "LW_USER_ROLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERACCOUNT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") }) 
List[Role]  roles
```

An `@JoinColumn` is inside `@JoinTable`.

A compilation error would be raised in Scala:

```
@JoinTable(name = "LW_USER_ROLE", joinColumns = Array(@JoinColumn(name = "USERACCOUNT_ID")))
var roles:List[StockEntity] = _
```

What is the equivalent grammar in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```scala
import java.util.{List => JList}


@JoinTable(
  name = "LW_USER_ROLE", 
  joinColumns = Array(new JoinColumn(name = "USERACCOUNT_ID")), 
  inverseJoinColumns = Array(new JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
) 
var roles:JList[StockEntity] = _
```